# gcc error when trying to use Windows Midi API

Tags: c++, gcc, midi

The problem is simple I'm trying to use the Windows API for Midi but gcc can't find the references for the Functions. I'm using MinGW and gcc version 9.2.0. The only solution to a similar problem i found was adding winmm.lib but that as well didn't help.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccV6si7i.o: in function `main':
c:/.../test.cpp:13: undefined reference to `midiInGetNumDevs@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the C++ code Producing the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

int main()
{
    MIDIINCAPS caps;

    UINT numberOfDevices = midiInGetNumDevs();
    if(numberOfDevices < 0){
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; ++i) {
            midiInGetDevCaps(i, &caps, sizeof(MIDIINCAPS));
            std::cout << i << " : name = " << caps.szPname << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")` That doesn't sound like a `#pragma` gcc understands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dxiv notes, you need to link the `winmm` library. GCC does not understand MSVC's `#pragma`, so it does not know it is needed. Therefore, linking fails when it does not find the functions.

See questions like [How to specify libraries paths in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455979/how-to-specify-libraries-paths-in-gcc) to learn how.